# Grails - Error saving JSONObject to MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am having trouble saving a JSONObject to a MongoDB database using the MongoDB plugin.

I receive the message:
`Can't find a codec for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject..`

This is very frustrating because I am using the JSON parser to load JSON data but can't persist this JSON data to the MongoDb which should be straightforward.

Is there a built in way to convert a JSONOBject to a normal Map? I've tried casting it using `asType( Map )`, `( Map )`, and even using `toString()` and thent rying to convert back from string to object. I've seen that other vanilla Java questions involve using Jackson but I'm hoping there is a Groovier way to do this rather than importing a whole new library for just two lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm doing for now:

Converting the JSONObject to a string and then using com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse() to convert that string to a DBObject that Mongo can use.

It's not the best but it works for now.

I'm not going to accept this answer because I don't think it's the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this is the correct answer, but I was able to convert the `JSONObject` to a `HashMap`. For my situation I had a Domain object with an `ArrayList` (converted from `JSONArray` by a previous JSONTranslationService) and I was able to convert each of the internal `JSONObject`s using something like this:

```
static final UNMARSHAL = { thing ->
  thing.objects.collect {
    it as Hashmap
  }
}
```

I'm only experiencing this issue after an upgrade from mongodb:3.0.2 to 6.1.2 to support MongoDB 3.4. Are you also running this version of the plugin? If so, I think it's fair to say that there's either a bug in the plugin (I'm already aware of [one](https://github.com/grails/gorm-mongodb/issues/34)) or something changed with the default behavior and wasn't documented.